# Can Cas 5.0 overlay jdbc lock account after x attempts.

Tags: java, security, jdbc, cas

I inherited a CAS server and have very little experience with it. I have been reading the docs but can't find how to do something I think is very simple.

So can Aspero CAS 5.0 overlay lock a user when using the jdbc authentication? I want to lock them after 3-5 attempts.

Pointing to any documentation on this would be appreciated. The only way i can think to add this would be possibly a stored procedure but CAS does not support that either.

I can handle locking if I can find a way to increment an attepts_to_login field. But would prefer CAS to set the locked flag itself.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming question, it might be more on topic on Server Fault.

Answer (score 0):

> So can Apereo CAS 5.0 overlay lock a user when using the jdbc authentication? I want to lock them after 3-5 attempts.

No. This requires code to handle the account locking.